# Metodo para agregar numeros de mayor a menor a una lista enlazada

Tags: javascript, lista

Con una lista enlazada vacía se tiene que crear un metodo para anadir numeros de mayor a menor, es decir:
head--> 50 --> 40 --> 25 --> 12 --> null
Si quisiera agregar un 30 el método lo pondría entre el 40 y el 25.

Estoy intentando usar este codigo pero por algun motivo no me funciona. Quizas no estoy entendiendo la logica del ejercicio.

```javascript
function LinkedList() {
    this._length = 0;
    this.head = null;
}

function Node(value){
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
}

LinkedList.prototype.add = function(val){
    if(this.head === null) {
        this.head = new Node(val);
    }
    if(this.head != null||this.head > val) {
        this.head = this.head.next;
    } else {
        while(this.head > val) {
            this.head = this.head.next;
        }
    }
  this.head = new Node(val);
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el constructor `Node`? Se me hace que uno de los problemas es la comparación de `val` con `this.head`

Comment: Listo, ya puse la función constructora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código presentaba varios errores, por ejemplo:

- Comprobar `val` que es un número contra `head` que es un `Node`
- La lógica en las condiciones de `if/else` estaba mal
- Nunca al nuevo nodo le asignabas el siguiente nodo de menor valor

Te dejo esta otra versión con comentarios en línea

```js
function Node(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.next = null;
}

function LinkedList() {
  this._length = 0;
  this.head = null;
}

LinkedList.prototype.add = function(val) {
  let newNode = new Node(val);
  let node = this.head;
  
  // Si la lista esta vacia
  if (node === null) {
    this.head = newNode;
  }
  // Si el primer node de la lista es menor
  else if (node.value < val) {
    this.head = newNode;
    newNode.next = node;
  }
  // Si el primer elemento de la lista es mayor
  else {
    // Mientra el siguiente nodo en la lista sea mayor
    while (node.next && node.next.value > val) {
      node = node.next;
    }
    // Al nuevo nodo asignamos el siguiente nodo al acutal
    newNode.next = node.next;
    // Al nodo actual asignamos el nuevo nodo
    node.next = newNode;
  }
}
LinkedList.prototype.print = function() {
  let list = [],
    node = this.head;
  while (node != null) {
    list.push(node.value)
    node = node.next;
  }
  list.push('NULL');
  console.log(list.join(' -> '));
}

list = new LinkedList();
list.add(12)
list.add(25)
list.add(40)
list.add(50)
list.add(30)
list.print()
```